# iosMath make label's text bold

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

iosMath is a library to render beautiful math equations on iOS.

my question is: How to make the MTMathUILabel's text bold?

Lets say I have a MTMathUILabel called label, I tried this and it didnt work:

```
(1) label.latex = "\\textbf{bold text}"
(2) label.latex = "{\\bf bold text}"
```

none of these worked, so I dont know what to do now

Comment: You might want to ask this on the iosMath issues page at GitHub: https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/issues

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I sent something there too. Anyway, still opened for help :)

Comment: Have you tried changing the font and/or its parameters? You may need to provide a custom font which supports bold style.

Comment: @Losiowaty no, I haven't tried to change because even if I do, I don't know how to make the Label display only bold text, so changing the font wouldn't make difference (but I may be wrong somehow).

Comment: Don't know the decorum on answering late for posterity. It's \\mathbf not \\textbf

Answer (score 1):

Try This

1. label.latex = "\\bf {bold text}"

add double slash(\\) instead of one.